# Can we union two tables with different number of columns such that the query adds the null columns itself by counting the extra columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, union, multiple-columns

I have tables where data has been fed across different time periods in the year. Although similar, these tables have different number of columns for each quarter. I know if I want to union two tables with different number of columns, the solution is just to add the extra number of columns as null columns.

However, in this case, I have more than 22 tables, each having 4 versions which need to be union. For example TableA_Q1 union TableA_Q2 union TableA_Q3 union TableA_Q4, and then repeat the same process for TableB_Q1 union TableB_Q2 and so on.

Right now, I am doing an intersect across 4 quarters for each of the Table and then started using excel to identify the remaining columns, but there has to be an easier way to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: No, you have to add the "null columns" explictly.

Comment: How about just using the columns that you need? My guess is that is a column isn't always there, then you wouldn't use it in a query anyway.

Comment: And watchout for union vs union all. union is slower and removes duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

you could use sys.columns and sys.tables to build dynamic sql, adding nulls as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can append the select you need  just adding null when you have not  corresponding column

the data type must corresponding too  eg :

```
    select col1, col2, col3, col4
    from TableA_Q1 
    UNION 
    select  col1, col2, null,null 
    from TableA_Q2 
    select  col1, col2, col5,null 
    from TableA_Q3 
    union 
    select  col1,null, col5,null
    from TableA_Q4
```

you can use union if you want remove duplicated  row  ..otherwise you can use UNION ALL for select all the rows

Answer (score -1):

You can use `join` to do that. Something like `select * from TableAQ1 join TableAQ2 on condition`. There are different kinds of join (`left`,`right`, `outter`..) but I think you want the outter one.

Edit: condition is `TableAQ1.calumnName = TableAQ2.columnName` where columnName is a column that relates in some way the information in the table. Sorry, i can't explain myself very well in english.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp

Comment: Why would those tables share a Primary key to join on?